# strcmp and strcpy is broken. I lost a word when i try to order them alphabetical in C

Tags: c, strcmp

right now I'm working on a bigger project. It's a long story, Santa Claus needs some help he has some cities and some toys to send. I need a function to order my cities alphabetical and i made one but, it worked fine for 9 tests and at the last one it bugged. Here's my function

```
void f_sort_city (structura_output s[], int n) {

int i, j;

structura_output AUX;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (strcmp(s[i].city, s[j].city) > 0) {

            strcpy(AUX.city, s[i].city);
            strcpy(s[i].city, s[j].city);
            strcpy(s[j].city, AUX.city);

            strcpy(AUX.toy, s[i].toy);
            strcpy(s[i].toy, s[j].toy);
            strcpy(s[j].toy, AUX.toy);

            AUX.nr_toy = s[i].nr_toy;
            s[i].nr_toy = s[j].nr_toy;
            s[j].nr_toy = AUX.nr_toy;
        }
    }
}
```

}

if i print the city before i order them everything is fine but after i lost a city

here is my struct that i use

```
typedef struct {
char city[100];
char toy[100];
int nr_toy;
} structura_output;
```

cant show you my imput it has 400+ lines but the cities that i use are

> ADDISA_ABABA
>   MALABO
>
> ALGER
>
> YAMOUSSOUKRO
>
> BUJUMBURA
>
> DJIBOUTI
>
> ASMARA
>
> KINSHASA
>
> BRAZZAVILLE
>
> CAIRO

and my output is

> ADDISA_ABABA
>
> ALGER
>
> ASMARA
>
> BRAZZAVILLE
>
> BUJUMBURA
>
> CAIRO

>

> DJIBOUTI
>
> KINSHASA
>
> MALABO

And i dont know hoe but i lost a city :\ Any kind of help would be awesome

Comment: how do you print your list? note: you could use `AUX = s[i];` etc... no need to swap all the fields, just use structure assignment, only 3 lines of code.

Comment: is there a _blank_ line when you're printing?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it worked with **AUX = s[i];** but now i'm losing a toy somehow :\ i mean i had 21 before and after i have 20

Comment: no, i don't write my own fuction

Comment: you need a [mcve] now. Even with 3 or 4 cities that could be enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: there's probably a memory corruption between the sort function and the display function, caused by some other code.

Comment: `strcmp` and `strcpy` are **not** broken.

Comment: What happens if you have only two cities in the list?

Comment: @MartinJames it worked with 50 cities but i dont know why for this input it dosent work :\

Comment: There is no need for `strcpy` (or the individual copy of any members), simply assign to `AUX`, e.g. `AUX = s[i]; s[i] = s[j]; s[j] = AUX;`

Answer (score 1):

You are not far off, but you are making things harder than they need to be. Since all members of your array are of fixed length, you can simply assign the structs. There is no need to do a *deep copy* copying each member. (that is needed where you have more than a single level of indirection in your members, like a *pointer to pointer to type*)

That shortens your `f_sort_city` function to:

```
void f_sort_city (structura_output s[], int n) {

    int i, j;

    structura_output AUX;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (strcmp(s[i].city, s[j].city) > 0) {
                AUX  = s[i];    /* no need to copy elements */
                s[i] = s[j];
                s[j] = AUX;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, depending on how you read your data file (you didn't show the code), if you are reading with a *line oriented* read (e.g. `fgets` or POSIX `getline`) make sure you remove the trailing `'\n'` read an included by the function.

Don't use *magic numbers* in your code, e.g. `char city[100];`, etc.. If you need constants, `#define` them (or use an `enum`), e.g.

```
#define MAXC 100    /* don't use 'magic numbers in your code */
#define MAXS 128    /* if you need constants, define them.  */
```

Putting it altogether, you could implement your read (from `stdin`) and sort similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 100    /* don't use 'magic numbers in your code */
#define MAXS 128    /* if you need constants, define them.  */

typedef struct {
    char city[MAXC];
    char toy[MAXC];
    int nr_toy;
} structura_output;

void f_sort_city (structura_output s[], int n) {

    int i, j;

    structura_output AUX;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (strcmp(s[i].city, s[j].city) > 0) {
                AUX  = s[i];    /* no need to copy elements */
                s[i] = s[j];
                s[j] = AUX;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {

    structura_output s[MAXS] = { {.city = ""} };
    size_t len, ndx = 0;

    while (ndx < MAXS && fgets (s[ndx].city, MAXC, stdin)) {
        len = strlen (s[ndx].city);                 /* get length */
        if (len && s[ndx].city[len - 1] == '\n')    /* test for newline */
            s[ndx].city[--len] = 0;                 /* trim newline */
        ndx++;  /* increment index */
    }

    f_sort_city (s, ndx);   /* sort data */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++)    /* output sorted data */
        printf ("s[%3zu] : %s\n", i, s[i].city);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you should also check that a complete line of data was read by checking whether `len + 1 == MAXC` if the check for `'\n'` fails)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/cities.txt
ADDISA_ABABA MALABO
ALGER
YAMOUSSOUKRO
BUJUMBURA
DJIBOUTI
ASMARA
KINSHASA
BRAZZAVILLE
CAIRO
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sortcities < dat/cities.txt
s[  0] : ADDISA_ABABA MALABO
s[  1] : ALGER
s[  2] : ASMARA
s[  3] : BRAZZAVILLE
s[  4] : BUJUMBURA
s[  5] : CAIRO
s[  6] : DJIBOUTI
s[  7] : KINSHASA
s[  8] : YAMOUSSOUKRO
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.